# Successfully tearing down tests

Tags: angularjs

I'm testing the code in one of my run blocks. Here's the test code thus far:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    describe('preflight.config',function() {

        var $rootScope, $state, jwtHelper, store;
        var id_token = "fdsafdsfsadfsadssafdsafs.eyJjb250YWN0Ijp7ImNyZWF0ZWRfYXQiOiIyMDE1LTExLTIzIDE3OjQyOjE1IFVUQyIsImdpZCI6ImdpZDovL2Zsb3dsZW5zL0NvbnRhY3QvMSIsImlkIjoxLCJ0b19zIjoiRGlhbm5hIEJhbGR3aW4iLCJ1cGRhdGVkX2F0IjoiMjAxNS0xMi0wNyAxNDozMzoxMSBVVEMiLCJjYW5fc2lnbl9pbiI6dHJ1ZSwiZW1haWwiOiJhbmRyZXcuY29jaHJhbmVAZmxvd2xlbnMuY29tIiwibmFtZSI6IkRpYW5uYSBCYWxkd2luIn0sImV4cCI6MTQ1MDE5NDg5MX0.EbXyENqN6YqYVrwy69iQq8AjoeEpjFcO23DdQChk7hI";
        var tokenPayload = {
            contact: {
                name: 'Flerp Derp',
                age: 26
            }
        };

        beforeEach(function() {
            module('app', function($provide) {
                var storeSpy = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(id_token);
                var jwtSpy = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(tokenPayload);

                $provide.value('jwtHelper', {
                    decodeToken: jwtSpy
                });
                $provide.value('store', {
                    get: storeSpy
                });
            }); 
            inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$state_, _jwtHelper_, _store_) {
                $rootScope     = _$rootScope_;
                $state          = _$state_;
                jwtHelper       = _jwtHelper_;
                store           = _store_;
            });
            spyOn($rootScope,'$on');
        });
        afterEach(function() {
            // How should this be properly torn down?
        });

        describe('store',function() {
            it('get() should be called with "id_token"',function() {
                expect(store.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('id_token');
            });
        });
        describe('$rootScope',function() {
            it('should be set tokenPayload.contact if jwt and contact is present',function() {
                expect($rootScope.currentUser).toBe(tokenPayload.contact);
            });
        });
    });
}());
```

This works fine - these tests pass. However I have to use `fdescribe` syntax to run this test in isolation by itself because it's breaking some of my other tests.

I believe that this is because I'm using `$provide` for constructing spies for certain dependencies simply because they occur in the run block.

Has anyone else encountered thus? I'm sure I need to correctly tear down the tests in the `afterEach` block but I not sure how.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In theory, test frameworks should start absolutely clean between every test. In practice, jasmine+angular don't do this. I think that the only thing you need to worry about persisting are module-wide values.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I agree - but should the approach be to nullify these values, change them to undefined or something else?

Comment: I think the approach should be to set them to whatever they started as. Maybe in your beforeEach you can do something like if (!!!myValue) myValue= _myValue_; and then set it back to that. If the value is of type object, maybe use angular.extend to copy the properties.